# Issue with NavigationBarTitle when scrolling List with TextFields inside of it

Tags: swift, list, swiftui, textfield, navigationbar

I have a simple checklist app that uses a SwiftUI `List` view to display sections with list items inside of it.

Because I want the list items to be editable, each list row has a `TextField` inside of it with the item name in it. However, if I focus into a text field and scroll the list before hitting the `Return Key`, the large `navigationBarTitle` has a bug where it remains frozen in place. For it to work properly, I have to back out of the page and come back.

I'm not seeing any errors, so I'm not sure why this occurring. I have a suspicion using a wrapped UITextField might solve this, but I'm not sure.

[image: SwiftUI List with TextFields scroll bug navigation bar large Title sticky]

Comment: Can you post a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? NavigationView + ScrollView/List is sometimes kind of glitchy

Comment: @aheze Thanks for the tip. I'm new to programming and as I tried to create an MRE I ended up solving my own problem! It was the result of a background color applied to the list and the group that contained the list.

Comment: Congrats, nice job!

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix my own issue while trying to create a reproducible example.

The bug was the result of a background color I was applying to the parent `Group` that contained the `List`. Removing the background color fixed my issue!

```
struct ChecklistView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if empty {
                EmptyView()
            } else {
                ListView()
            }
        }
        .background(Color(.tertiarySystemBackground).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)) // removing this line fixed my issue
        .navigationBarTitle("My title")
    }
}
```